# Compare 2 datasets using PowerPivot

Tags: excel, compare, comparison, powerpivot

I have to compare different datasets to find deviations between them.
Datasets are always a multicolumn table (up to 1000 columns).

Currently I use plain Excel workbook and compare 2 sheets cell-by-cell with a formula:

```
=IF(Master!A2=Test!A2);0;Master!A2&"/"&Test!A2)
```

So it is a zero if no deviation and 2 values separated with slash if they differ.

However, if the input (plain text/ CSV) files are too big, like containing >50k rows, Excel becomes veeery slow.

Is there any solution to do this using PowerPivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerpivot isn't created to compare excel files. If you have excel 2013, you could use the excel compare feature.

more info:

[Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205148.aspx)

[Excel 2013 compare](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/722-tips-comparing-two-workbooks-excel2013-compare-files-feature)

Comment: thanks for the method. However it process only up to 100mn cells. Is there  any way to compare more? Possibly, some SQL-based solution?

Comment: yes, if you can write sql code it will be easier. 
you have a lot of methods for this, this site explains a lot of popular methods: [https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/on-comparing-tables-in-sql-server/](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/on-comparing-tables-in-sql-server/)

If you are interested in paying tools: sql compare from redgate is popular compare tool.